# How to declare a variable which can be set into a param of type std::chrono::milliseconds

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have the following method which intakes `std::chrono::milliseconds`

```
void SomeMethod(std::chrono::milliseconds some_value) {

  // some logic
}
```

I am able to call it in the following way:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
SomeMethod(1000ms);
```

Works.
**But**, I want to call it in the following way by passing a member variable or some globally declared variable. Something like this,

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
std::chrono::system_clock::duration timeout = 3000ms;
```

But I get the following error:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'duration<[...], ratio<[...], 1000000>>' to 'duration<[...], ratio<[...], 1000>>'
SomeMethod(some_value);
                                                                             ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: Shouldn't your initialization be : std::chrono::milliseconds timeout = 3000ms;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you're trying to convert microseconds into milliseconds. `system_clock::duration` must be a typedef for `std::chrono::microseconds` on your platform.

You can implicitly convert from `milliseconds` to `microseconds` as in your `std::chrono::system_clock::duration timeout = 3000ms;` line, but to convert the other way you need a `duration_cast`:

```
std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeout);
```

Comment: Note that this cast can be lossy.  If system clock time units is minutes (!) 3000ms will map to 0 minutes, which may not be what you want.  Then again, your platform as a clock that every ticks every minute, so maybe you have bigger problems.